# Slim guy-chest-define low pecs at home

Tags: workout-routines, chest

[image: Make it to be more and strong-defined as this on]

I want to do my low pec like this on screen.I am doing push ups (elevated).What are the possible workouts i can do at home to obtain like this?If i need to add i can.I am eating right.I need only home workouts to obtain this definision on lower "area" of my pecs.

Comment: Short answer: Try increase difficulty of push ups by trying different variations or adding some weight to your back. Aim to decrease the number of reps you have to perform before suffering from fatigue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite popular belief the chest actually grows evenly. To grow a chest that size and gain definition it is important you have more variation in your exercises or more weight. Just off body weight alone any of the 3 basic push-ups will not be enough to put on size on your chest.

Personally, I believe you should try looking into Calisthenics and doing different things to push yourself and work your chest. As well as this I recommend wearing a backpack filled with books or something heavy when you perform these exercises to provide more resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are no shortcut for that peck. 
Sure, bodybuilders will show you movements that help define that particular part of chest, but even if those exercises work - they are performed by people who already able to bench their body weight for 5-10 reps. Can you do that?

Also, it could be dangerous to **just** do a lot of push ups. You could dis-balance your upper body. Surprisingly, it is very common to have shoulder issues because of "over trained" chest in comparison to back.

If you have to stick with home workouts, I'd do at least pull ups, push ups, squats, with approximate ratio of 1-2-3. E.g.:

For each pull up, you do 2 push ups, and 3 squats. This will give you more balance.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to target the lower chest with home workouts, then there are 2 things that I highly recommend.

1. Start doing dips. Because you are pushing downward as opposed to in front of your body (like with push-ups), the lower chest is activated more. Bodybuilders use decline bench press and dips as a way of targeting the lower chest because they both have this downward pushing motion.
2. If you want to take this one step further then I recommend doing gymnastic ring dips. Doing dips with rings instead of on fixed bars makes your chest work extra hard because not only does it have to push, it has to stabilize the rings too.

It's easy to get a gymnastic ring set up at home, all you need is rings and a pull-up bar to hang them from. If you want to check out the specific pull up bar and rings I recommend for home workouts, you can check out this article I have written on my website:

Comment: Welcome to the site! This could be a strong answer, however I have had to remove the links, as your post was marked as spam. You are welcome to keep the link to your website in your profile, and summarize the relevant information in the answer. Anything else will be flagged and removed as spam. I would encourage you to read the help section and take the tour to find out more about how SE works.

Comment: @JohnP: Isn't it acceptable to provide such links when the attribution is fully disclosed, as they have done? (https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) Admittedly, it would be better if they provided that information in place of, or in addition to, their link.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - "Don't include links except to support what you've written.". The statements were basically "I have a good workout routine, read here" followed by "I recommend rings, see my article here". It is acceptable to occasionally use a link in *support of what you write here*, not say "read this over here". Using your homepage link in your profile is always acceptable.

Comment: @JohnP: That's fair. :) I guess I just felt like it might be coming off as "you can't include links to your personal site". So, just to be clear for user29057, if they write up the exercises they're linking, they'd be fine?

Comment: @SeanDuggan absolutely. Just as a caveat, it is frowned upon to always use your link in your posts. You can refer to it, but that is what the profile link is for, to provide the actual link.